# Bash-based Hot Reload Implementation

Tags: linux, bash, unit-testing, automated-tests, git-bash

**tl;dr version**
Question: How to make a bash script / command to listen to changes to a file and then output the result of a specific Bash command?

**Long version**
Real Scenario: I am refactoring a Perl module (*my_module.pm*) and I have a test file which associates to that module (*my_module.t*). I would like to put the console on one screen, and whenever I saves the pm file (using the editor on another screen) the console would run `prove -v my_module.t`.

Background: I have all permissions in the current directory, and if needed I can elevate to `sudo`. I don't mind if the implementation is something like `setInterval` since it's for development purposes only. As long as I have a way to `clearInterval` and the script doesn't produce never-ending output when the file isn't changed then it's good :)

Example Scenario:
Assume the bash script is named `hot` and it runs `ls -l source.txt` whenever the file given is changed.
So when I run `hot source.txt`, the script may or may not run `ls ....` once. And then when I modify `source.txt`, the console running `hot` will run the `ls` again and I should see the new file size (along with other info) of `source.txt`.
If I run `hot something.txt`, when`source.txt`is modified, it shouldn't run`ls`. And even if `source.txt` is not modified, the script should trigger `ls` whenever I modify `something.txt`.

I guess this is possible with a `while` loop but I have difficulty in tracking file changes (and best to track with an interval to be less resource-heavy). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have access to `inotify`?

Comment: I guess *yes* - I don't have access to the virtual machine now, but it was built on CentOS so I guess yes...

Comment: Can you do a quick confirmation of it using `which inotifywait`? and see if it is present. It is quite simply using that,  or download as in https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki

Comment: `which inotifywait`: /usr/bin/which: no inotifywait in (...)
And also the same result when I tried to run `which inotify`...
I have `sudo` access and can run `yum install` for it if that helps solving the hot-reloading issue though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up coming up with this function to my `~/.bashrc`:

```
function hot {
  if (( $# < 2 )); then
    echo 'USAGE: hot <command> <file1> [<file2> ... <fileN>]'
    echo '<command> will be run once when any of the files listed is changed (i.e. ls -l <file> has its output changed)'
  else
    script=$1
    shift
    a='';
    while true; do
      b=`ls -l $*`
      [[ $a != $b ]] && a=$b && eval $script;
      sleep .5;
    done
  fi
}
```

So I could do `hot 'prove my_module.t' my_module.pm`, and as stated in the example I can also do `hot 'ls -l source.txt' source.txt`.

In practical, I would like the test to be run once the file or the test file has been changed.  Thus I'd do `hot 'prove my_module.t' my_module.pm my_module.t`.

The line `[[ $a != $b ]] && a=$b && eval $script;` is to avoid confusing myself with nested-if - it is a "short form" of doing `a=$b; eval $script` if `$a != $b`.

Hope this helps someone else looking for an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`inotifywait`](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) to monitor the file for change events and run the test on its modification.

```
inotifywait -q -m -e close_write my_module.pm |
while read -r filename event; do
  prove -v my_module.t
done
```

The usage of the flags are as follows. The event `-e` flag in your case is `close_write` which means the file has been closed after being opened for writing recently.

```
-q, --quiet

If specified once, the program will be less verbose. Specifically, it will not state when 
it has completed establishing all inotify watches. If specified twice, the 
program will output nothing at all, except in the case of fatal errors.

-m, --monitor

Instead of exiting after receiving a single event, execute indefinitely. The default 
behaviour is to exit after the first event occurs.

-e <event>, --event <event>

Listen for specific event(s) only.

close_write

A watched file or a file within a watched directory was closed, after being opened in 
writeable mode. This does not necessarily imply the file was written to.
```

Comment: Mm.. My box has lost its outgoing connection, so I am transferring the `.tar.gz` to the machine, however I am not very familiar with `autoreconf` and `automake` (not sure about the command line options). Which commands may help me getting `inotify-tools` installed?

Comment: @SunnyPun: Just do `./configure --prefix=/usr && make && su -c 'make install'` as mentioned in the page, do it inside the folder, after extracting the archive

Comment: Oh silly me... I hit this error when running `inotifywait`: `inotifywait: error while loading shared libraries: libinotifytools.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. The installation seems going well except `ldconfig: /usr/lib/libinotifytools.so.0 is not a symbolic link`.

Comment: @SunnyPun: Add another option to `./configure` as `./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/lib64 && make && su -c 'make install'`

Comment: Thanks for your patience.. Now I am running this `inotifywait -q -m -e close_write gg.txt |
> while read -r filename event; do
>   ls
> done`
And doing `vi gg.txt` in the same folder on another bash (and using `:x` to save the file).  This gives me no output... What should I do?

Comment: @SunnyPun: Can you try adding some content to the file and close it? and what does `do > ls > done` mean? AM not sure that is syntactically valid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134954/discussion-between-sunny-pun-and-inian).

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort.  `inotifywait` can capture changes by `nano`, but not `vi` nor changes synced from host machine (In fact I am editing code on host and get my box running the tests...).  I'll see if there are better solutions.